# tileoverlay layer not updating when animate camera to track user location update

Tags: android, google-maps

Dears, I got an issue using Android SDK with google map support.

I need to show on top of the base layer another layer with some custom data. Everything works since I configured a TileProvider, do the conversion from xy format to lat/lon and add to map overlay layers.

Then I track user location while using the app: once I got the new location, I update the map center thus simulating the map moving with the user at the center while keeping overlays active and visible:
[image: user loc and overlay are visible]

Problem is keeping both work togheter.
When user moves out of the loaded tiles, the tiles are not updating automatically even if the viewport changed resulting the empty layer
[image]

If the user interacts manually with the app, it works.
No issues with the base layer, handled by Google.

Multiple solutions come to mind:

- whenever the user loc update callback gets invoked, it clears and and the overlay again. This solution will cause a flickr effect.
- simulate a "touch".

What's the correct way to keep overlay loaded like in the "not moving map" case?

Best,
FB

Comment: How about you try using the [onCameraMoveListener](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk/reference/com/google/android/libraries/maps/GoogleMap.OnCameraMoveListener) to load the tile? Would that work?

Comment: This approach could work even if it could be triggered a lot of times and trying to download a similar tile multiple times. See if I could find something better.